# Find the smallest open set such that a complex function admits a primitive.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm given a complex function h(z)=1/z^2-2/(z^2-1)+4/(z^2-4), and I need to find an open set Ω that satisfies the following:
[image]

How do I approach the third condition? (I know that h does not admit a primitive on its domain, but I have no clue on how to shrink it to the smallest open set on which the primitive exists.)

Comment: Hint: map out where the poles are.

Comment: Yes I know the poles are at -2,-1,0,1,2, but how should I use them to approach this

Comment: Is there any combination of poles you can integrate around that is $0$?

Comment: In the title, "compact open set" does not make sense.